# how to push back / repel clothes from a surface?

Tags: modeling, cloth-simulation

[image: clothes with holes]

Hello!

I am trying to design clothes to a character that I made.

And I get stuck on that problem:
Is there an easy trick to repel the clothes from the body.

I modeled the clothes above my model but the holes keep happening.
I tried with shrink wrap Offset but it just makes the clothes to wide.
I tried to use the cloth simulator, but it doesn't solve the problem, and adds a lot of wrinkles.

thanks for the help,
Mathieu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go into edit mode with a piece of clothing selected.

Enable proportional editing by pressing <kbd>O</kbd>. Turn on x-ray with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> in order to help you see the mesh stuck inside the model more easily.

Select a vertice that is inside the person, pull the vertice out of the character. Adjust the proportional size with your scroll wheel. This will determine how nearby vertices are affected. Repeat with other clothes.

Comment: cool it worked!